# Delete Facebook Business manager account

Tags: facebook

I have a question...Last mont I've created a Business Manager Account linked to one page of mine in facebook, but I've never done an ads or campaign, so I've any cost charged. If I disable my business account, facebook will charge me a cost or anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about programming.

Comment: OK. Sorry for my mistake. Can you tell me if there is a section in stackoverflow where can i post this question?

Comment: You can contact facebook and ask them. This has nothing to do with any StackExchange sites.

Comment: @ElisaLtc Not on Stack Overflow, since it’s for programming questions, but there are [other sites on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites), not sure if one of them would be suitable.

Comment: @Biffen Thank you very much :)